# Adding RelativeLayout inside a fully occupied LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

So I have a `LinearLayout` equally divided and occupied by `buttons` (total of 25 buttons). What I wanted is to open a `fragment` whenever one of the buttons is clicked. However, I don't know how to or if it is even possible to add another `RelativeLayout` inside my `LinearLayout`.

If there are other ways to show a fragment inside an `Activity` with a fully occupied Layout I would gladly appreciate it.

Here is my LinearLayout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="dagger.com.koin.Levels.Level_1"
    android:background="@drawable/test">



    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:onClick="onClick">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/A"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:background="@drawable/blank_button"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/B"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:background="@drawable/blank_button"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/C"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:background="@drawable/blank_button"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/D"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:background="@drawable/blank_button"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/E"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:background="@drawable/blank_button"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/F"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:background="@drawable/blank_button"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/G"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:background="@drawable/blank_button"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/H"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/blank_button"
            android:onClick="onClick" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/I"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:background="@drawable/blank_button"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/J"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:background="@drawable/blank_button"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/K"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:background="@drawable/blank_button"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/L"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/blank_button"
            android:onClick="onClick" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/M"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/blank_button"
            android:onClick="onClick" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/N"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/blank_button"
            android:onClick="onClick" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/O"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:background="@drawable/blank_button"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/P"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:background="@drawable/blank_button"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Q"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:background="@drawable/blank_button"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/R"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/blank_button"
            android:onClick="onClick" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/S"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/blank_button"
            android:onClick="onClick" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/T"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/blank_button"
            android:onClick="onClick" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/U"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:background="@drawable/blank_button"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/V"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/blank_button"
            android:onClick="onClick" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/W"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/blank_button"
            android:onClick="onClick" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/X"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:background="@drawable/blank_button"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Y"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/blank_button"
            android:onClick="onClick" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: explain your purpose briefly, please

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question properly you want to show a fragment on given button click from your layout.
I have done it for a single button similarly you can do it for all the buttons.

public class Test extends AppCompatActivity{

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test_layout);

}


public void onClick(View v){
   switch (v.getId()){
       case R.id.A:
           showFragment(new FragmentA());
           break;
   }
}

public void showFragment(Fragment arg_frg) {
    FrameLayout layout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
    layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container,arg_frg).commit();
}
```

}

and a small change to your given layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:visibility="gone">

    </FrameLayout>


    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:onClick="onClick">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/A"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:text="A"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/B"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClick"
          />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/C"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClick"

            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/D"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClick"
           />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/E"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClick"
          />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/F"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClick"
          />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/G"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClick"
           />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/H"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:onClick="onClick" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/I"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClick"
           />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/J"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClick"
          />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/K"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClick"

            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/L"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:onClick="onClick" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/M"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:onClick="onClick" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/N"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:onClick="onClick" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/O"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClick"
  />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/P"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClick"

            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Q"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClick"
          />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/R"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:onClick="onClick" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/S"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:onClick="onClick" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/T"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:onClick="onClick" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/U"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClick" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/V"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClick" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/W"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:onClick="onClick" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/X"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClick"
           />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Y"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClick" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```